# About the quick assist in AD domain environment

Tags: windows, active-directory

My company network is MS AD domain environment.

All my client's PC are joined the AD domain.

Therefore, I must connect the client's PC when my user needs the admin. right.

I can connect to my client's PC using the Windows 10 feature "quick assist".

Unfortunately, when the client's PC prompt the admin. user name and password, I got a black screen on my PC. Is it normal? How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The black screen is normal and happens when the remote side is presented with the UAC and username/password prompt for the secure desktop. It's a security feature.

To avoid the black screen, set the machine policy "Switch to the secure desktop when prompting for elevation" to disabled. This will present the UAC prompt and the username/password input on the user's regular desktop instead of in the secure desktop. The secure desktop is by default not visible on the remote side of the connection until the user has completed the UAC and username/password prompts.

The policy is in `Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options`

Comment: Is it the AD domain global policy?

Comment: Yes, unless you have some clients that shouldn't have the policy.

Comment: For reference, Microsoft's official doc on this particular setting is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/user-account-control-switch-to-the-secure-desktop-when-prompting-for-elevation